# How many groups up isomorphisms exist such that has least one element of order 8.

Tags: group-theory

Calculate how groups up isomorphisms exist of order 88 such that has least one element of order 8.

I have two groups: $\mathbb{Z}_{88}$ (abelian) and $\mathbb{Z_{11}}\rtimes_{\phi}\mathbb{Z}_8$, where $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{8}\rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{11})$, defined by $y\mapsto \phi(y)(a)=a^{10}$, $a\in \mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

There are other groups?

Thank you by some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $n_{11}$ of 11-Sylow subgroup should satisfy $n_{11} \equiv _{11} 1$ and $n_{11} \mid 88/11=8$ so you must have that $n_11=1$, or equivalently there is only 1 normal 11-Sylow subgroup. Similarly, the number of 2-Sylow group is odd and divides $88/8=11$ so it is either 1 or 11.

If there is one 2-Sylow subgroup, then it is normal and you get that $G=P_{11}\times P_8$ (since $P_{11},P_8$ are both normal, their intersection is $\{e\}$ and generate $G$. Since 11 is prime you must have that $P_{11}$ is cyclic, and there are exactly 5 groups of order 8 (3 abelian groups, the quaternions and dihedral). So you already have 5 non isomorphic groups.
EDIT: just noticed the condition about element of order 8, so this group must be the cyclic group of order 8

Assume now that there is more then one 2-Sylow subgroup. Since $P_{11}$ is normal in $G$, you still get a semidirect product $P_{11}\rtimes P_8$, so you need to find all the action of a group of order 8 on a cyclic group of order 11. Any such action is defined by a homomorphism $\psi:P_8\to Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{11})$. You can now use the fact that $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{11})\cong \mathbb{Z}_{10} \cong \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Since 8,5 are coprime, the image of $P_8$ must be contained in the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ part. You can now go over all the group of order 8 and find all the homomorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (namely, find the subgroup of index 2), and try to understand what is the group.
EDIT: Since $P_8$ must be cyclic, it has exactly 1 (nontrivial) such homomorphism, so there is exactly one non abelian group with element of order 8.